Proof verification on Functional analysis excercise

Let $E$ be a Banach space and $T \in \mathcal{L}(E)$ with $\lVert T \rVert < 1$ . We denote by $T^0 = I$ where $I$ is the identity map of $E$ and $T^k = T \circ \overset{k}{\dots} \circ T$ for $k \in \Bbb{N}$ . Prove that

$\sum_{k \geq 0} T^k$ converges on $E$
$I-T$ has an inverse on $\mathcal{L}(E)$ . As a suggestion, denote for all $n \in \Bbb{N} : S_n = \sum_{k=0}^n T^k \in \mathcal{L}(E)$ and compute $(I-T) S_n$ and $S_n (I-T)$ .


I am trying to solve this excercise from my Functional analysis book. For $1$ I think that  we just need to observe that $$\sum_{k \geq 0} \lVert T^k \rVert \leq \sum_{k \geq 0} \lVert T \rVert^k = \frac{1}{1- \lVert T \rVert} $$
and, since $E$ is a Banach space, every absolute convergent series is convergent, so $\sum_{k \geq 0} T^k$ converges on $E$ .
On $2$, for all $x \in E$ we have:
$$(I-T)S_n (x) = (I-T) ( \sum_{k=0}^n T^kx) = \sum_{k=0}^n T^kx - \sum_{k=0}^n T^{k+1}x = x - T^{n+1}x = (I-T^{n+1})x \\ S_n(I-T) (x) = S_n(x-Tx) = \sum_{k=0}^n T^kx - \sum_{k=0}^n T^{k+1}x = x - T^{n+1}x = (I-T^{n+1})x$$
Therefore $$(I-T)S_n = I-T^{n+1} = S_n(I-T) \hspace{1cm} (*)$$
Denote by $Sx := \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} S_nx$ . By $1$ we can conclude that $S$ is well defined, $S_n \rightarrow S$ in $\mathcal{L}(E)$ and, since $\lVert T \rVert < 1 \implies \lVert T^k \rVert \rightarrow 0 \implies T^k \rightarrow 0$ so taking limits on $(*)$ we have: $$(I-T) S = I = S (I-T) $$
Is this fine?

This is correct, yes.

@BrunoB Thanks!

read [tag:solution-verification] description here
